# Performing Date calculations with string arguments like "2.months"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, date, calculation

I'm trying to perform some `Date` calculations in a Ruby on Rails project where I have a `period` variable and have to do something like `Date.current - period`

Because the `period` variable holds a string like `"2.months"`, when I perform the above calculation I get a `expected numeric` error.

Is there any workaround that doesn't involve using the `eval` method or any other methods not considered "safe"?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to parse the string yourself, and in doing that ensure that it's safe, for example:

```rb
str = '2.months'

regex = /^(?<number>\d{1,2})\.(?<unit>months?|days?)$/

test = str.match regex

puts test[:number] => '2'
puts test[:unit] => 'months'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `send`:

```rb
> num, period = '2.months'.split('.')
> num.to_i.send(period).ago # Equivalent to Date.current - period
```

It should work with second[s], minute[s], ..., day[s], week[s], etc.

See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html and https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html